# Requiring a package in composer that is not PSR compliant

Tags: composer-php

I'd like to just pull the following package in using composer so it will be autoloaded, but can't figure out how (or if) that can be done:
https://code.google.com/p/freshbooks-php-library/

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the question is a little old, but I don't think you can include packages, archives or libraries without the target resource containing a (valid) composer.json in the project root.

However; Google has given me this repo https://github.com/Isinlor/freshbooks-php which would seem to do the trick.

Comment: After much trying I believe you are correct sir. There might be some obscure hack, but not worth my time.